How should I analyse TV episode popularity while accounting for time?
I have a toy dataset which contains TV episodes, the date they were released and how many streams they have received:



episode
date
streams




The Shadow Realm
2024-03-08
5987


The Forbidden Tome
2024-03-01
6315


The Devil's Tea
2024-02-23
9584


The Sorcerer's Shoes
2024-02-16
8996


The Enchanted Forest
2024-02-09
7564


The Echoing Abyss
2024-02-02
7982


The Lost Civilization
2024-01-26
8456


The Dimensional Rift
2024-01-19
8834


The Crystal Maze
2024-01-12
9215


The Scepter of Zalthar
2024-01-05
9763



I am interested in analysing the number of streams each episode receives.
In particular, from the data we can see that the longer an episode has been available, the more streams it receives (in general). At the same time, some more recent episodes have a higher than "expected" number of streams against their release date (here those episodes are The Devil's Tea and the Sorcerer's Shoes).
What method of analysis should I use to determine the popularity of each episode (higher streams = more popular) while accounting/controlling for the effect of time (earlier release date = higher streams)?
The data is also given below in an R dput format if helpful.
structure(list(episode = c("The Shadow Realm", "The Forbidden Tome", 
"The Devil's Tea", "The Sorcerer's Shoes", "The Enchanted Forest", 
"The Echoing Abyss", "The Lost Civilization", "The Dimensional Rift", 
"The Crystal Maze", "The Scepter of Zalthar"), date = structure(c(19790, 
19783, 19776, 19769, 19762, 19755, 19748, 19741, 19734, 19727
), class = "Date"), streams = c(5987, 6315, 9584, 8996, 7564, 
7982, 8456, 8834, 9215, 9763)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))


Assuming this is just toy data to give the flavor of the problem and you have more observations, I would try

fitting a heteroscedasticity-robust Poisson model of streams on episode age
calculating the expected number of streams at each age, along with a 95% CI

This should look something like this:


R Code
# Uncomment the following lines to install the required packages if 
# not already installed
# install.packages(c("tidyverse", "lubridate", "sandwich", "emmeans", "ggrepel"))

# Load necessary libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(sandwich)
library(emmeans)
library(ggrepel)

# Input data
data <- tibble(
  episode = c("The Shadow Realm", "The Forbidden Tome", 
               "The Devil's Tea", 
              "The Sorcerer's Shoes", "The Enchanted Forest", 
              "The Echoing Abyss", 
              "The Lost Civilization", "The Dimensional Rift", 
              "The Crystal Maze", 
              "The Scepter of Zalthar"),  # Episode titles
  date = as_date(c("2024-03-08", "2024-03-01", "2024-02-23", 
                   "2024-02-16", "2024-02-09", "2024-02-02", 
                   "2024-01-26", "2024-01-19", "2024-01-12", 
                   "2024-01-05")),  # Episode release dates
  streams = c(5987, 6315, 9584, 8996, 7564, 7982, 8456, 8834, 9215, 
                9763)  # Number of streams
) %>%
  mutate(age_in_days = as.numeric(ymd("2024-07-11") - date),  
# Calculate age of each episode in days
  outlier = ifelse(streams > 8900 & age_in_days < 150, episode, NA))  

# Identify outliers based on streams and age

# Poisson regression model with robust standard errors
model <- glm(streams ~ age_in_days, data = data, 
             family = quasipoisson())  # Fit Poisson regression model
robust_vcov <- vcovHC(model, type = "HC1")  
# Calculate robust variance-covariance matrix (HC1)

# Generate new data for prediction
new_data <- tibble(age_in_days = 125:188)  
# Create a new data frame for age_in_days range

# Predictions with confidence intervals using emmeans
emm <- emmeans(model, ~ age_in_days, at = list(age_in_days = 125:188),
                 vcov = robust_vcov, type = "response")
emm_summary <- summary(emm)

# Print the column names of emm_summary to check
print(colnames(emm_summary))

# Convert emm_summary to a data frame and rename columns based on actual names
emm_df <- as.data.frame(emm_summary)
colnames(emm_df) <- c("age_in_days", "fitted", "SE", "df", "conf.low",
                      "conf.high")

# Ensure new_data matches emmeans summary
new_data <- left_join(new_data, emm_df, by = "age_in_days")  
# Merge new_data with emm_df

# Plot
ggplot(new_data, aes(x = age_in_days, y = fitted)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +  # Plot fitted values as a line
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), 
  linetype = "dashed", alpha = 0.1) +  
# Add confidence interval ribbon
  geom_point(data = data, aes(x = age_in_days, y = streams)) +  
# Plot actual data points
  geom_text_repel(data = data, aes(x = age_in_days, y = streams, 
                  label = outlier), 
                  na.rm = TRUE, box.padding = 0.35, 
                  point.padding = 0.3, angle = 0) +  
# Label outliers with episode names
  theme_minimal() +  # Apply minimal theme
  labs(x = "Age in Days", y = "Streams") +  # Add axis labels
  theme(legend.position = "none")  # Remove legend

Stata Code
Same results, but I cannot quite match the CI from R, probably due to different HC and small sample corrections. Differences should be less stark with a larger sample.
clear
input str30 episode str10 date int streams
"The Shadow Realm" "2024-03-08" 5987
"The Forbidden Tome" "2024-03-01" 6315
"The Devil's Tea" "2024-02-23" 9584
"The Sorcerer's Shoes" "2024-02-16" 8996
"The Enchanted Forest" "2024-02-09" 7564
"The Echoing Abyss" "2024-02-02" 7982
"The Lost Civilization" "2024-01-26" 8456
"The Dimensional Rift" "2024-01-19" 8834
"The Crystal Maze" "2024-01-12" 9215
"The Scepter of Zalthar" "2024-01-05" 9763
end
gen age_in_days = td(11jul2024) - date(date,"YMD")
gen outlier = episode if streams > 8900 & age_in_days < 150
glm streams age_in_days, vce(robust) family(poisson) irls // irr
margins, at(age_in_days = (125(1)188)) post
marginsplot, addplot(scatter streams age_in_days, ms(Oh) mlab(outlier) mlabangle(20) mlabpos(2)) recastci(rline) ciopt(lpattern(dash)) recast(line) legend(off)


Great answer and visualization (+1). I changed 'het' to 'heteroscedasticity', hope you don't mind.

This looks nice. Can you explain how you arrived at the values 8900 and 150 in the second line of code: outlier = ifelse(streams > 8900 & age_in_days < 150, episode, NA)? It looks like these are values outside the model's confidence intervals, but you do this before you run the model.

@SamR I kind of cheated: eyeballed from the graph and then defined the labels earlier on. I am sure there is a better way to do the labels, but I was being lazy.

@FransRodenburg I agree. Good edit!

Honestly, to me, it looks a lot like all the non-outlier episodes fall almost exactly on a straight line of views versus age, one that predicts them better than the Poisson model. To be precise, a model like y = 59.65x-1589 with a product-moment correlation coefficient of something like 0.999. That would suggest that simply dividing the number of streams minus the intercept by days (or better, hours) since release and comparing to the expected number might be a good measure of popularity.

Of course, this wouldn't work as well with many real data sets, I imagine. But in the case of something that clearly is highly linear with a few outliers from a completely different distribution—as this, presumably intentionally created, data seems to be....

The data is a tad weird because despite the non-outliers nearly perfectly matching a linear trend, the number of predicted views is negative until the episode has been out for about 27 days. If I saw that in real data with such perfect linearity, I would suspect that the episodes were effectively not available for the first month, perhaps as a consequence of being from very obscure and unpopular shows and not being recommended anywhere except searches until reaching a low threshold of views. Which might make sense: these numbers are a good 3–4 orders of magnitude below what, say, Netflix has.

Why is poisson regression applicable when the variance is 200 times the mean?

I've asked this in a new question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/650973/how-much-dispersion-is-too-much-for-quasipoisson-regression

Observations lying outside of confidence intervals is hardly an indication of it being an outlier. You should look at prediction intervals or standardized residuals instead.

@rolando2 The het-robust Poisson estimator is consistent if the conditional mean is correctly specified. It will also be efficient in the class of robust estimators when the variance is proportional to the mean, so both over- and underdispersion are allowed.

@LukasLohse Is that possible with the sandwich variance? I agree that outlier was an unfortunate name for the variable to label the two unusual movies.

@dimitriy Not really and not really with with quasipoisson at all. I'm not sure why you used either when establishing the general trend was not the question.

Poisson or quasipoisson would give the same point estimates. I used the sandwich variance because the homoskedastic SEs would be much too small, given the overdispersion.

@dimitriy Those are mostly an issue, because you are trying to include the outliers. Which is the correct thing for estimating the overall trend, but doesn't help you with identifying weird observations, after you already know that there is a trend and some outliers from that trend.

Thank you for this answer, it is very helpful. As some have wondered about this, yes, the true data will not match the linear trend so closely.
